# How to add email servern & port into this PHP

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP code at my server in which if data is added to the database, it sends a mail to the admin. Recently I bought a webhosting and uploaded my files. Problem is my mails from the server were getting delayed so I asked the webhosting. They said me to add this "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" and port 25 in my PHP to receive the mail fast. I don't have much knowledge of PHP. Can you help me where to insert this in the code below:

```
<?php

// get data 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
$kota = $_POST['kota'];
$provinsi = $_POST['provinsi'];
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
$date_n_time = $_POST['date_n_time'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$order_list = $_POST['order_list'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$emails = $_POST['email'];

$sql_query = "set names 'utf8'";
$stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {    
    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute();
    // store result 
    $stmt->close();
}

// insert data into reservation table
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_reservation(Name, Alamat, Kota, Provinsi, Number_of_people, Date_n_Time, Phone_number, Order_list, Comment, Email) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {    
    // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss', 
                $name,
                $alamat,    
                $kota,  
                $provinsi,  
                $name2, 
                $date_n_time, 
                $phone, 
                $order_list,
                $comment,
                $emails
                );
    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->affected_rows;
    // store result 
    //$result = $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->close();
}

// get admin email from user table
$sql_query = "SELECT Email 
        FROM tbl_user";

$stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {    
    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute();
    // store result 
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($email);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}

// if new reservation has been successfully added to reservation table 
// send notification to admin via email
if($result){
    $to = $emails;
    $subject = $reservation_subject_2;
            $message .= "Dear " .$provinsi."\r\n";
    $message .= $reservation_message_2."\r\n\n";
            $message .= "Pick Drop :" .$name2."\r\n";

    $from = $admin_email;
    $headers = "From:" . $from."\r\n".
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "OK";
}else{
    echo "Failed";
}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using PHP's built in `mail()` command to send the message - you can see that line almost at the end of your code:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

The server and port that `mail()` [uses are configured in PHP's configuration file, php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).  You may be able to override those settings by adding this to your code - anywhere above the `mail()` line.

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net');
ini_set('smtp_port', 25);
```

If you want to use that server/port always, from other PHP code, you'll either need to make the same change in the other files that send mail, or update the main php.ini configuration file.

Comment: trying it. I will reply back in a while